# How do I add standard scroll bars to a SurfaceView?

Tags: android, scroll, scrollbar, surfaceview

I got a SurfaceView, in which I display a bitmap that is much larger than the actual area of the SurfaceView, so I have implemented a way for the user to slide their finger on the bitmap and move it up and down. When doing so, I would like to be able to display a vertical scroll bar, preferably the standard Android scroll bars, instead of drawing something custom.

The thing is, I would like my SurfaceView to stay the size of the screen, that is I don't want to scroll the SurfaceView itself, I just want to create the illusion that the user is scrolling the contents, and therefore display the scrollbars.

I tried setting android:scrollbars = "vertical" in the layout's XML, I tried mSurfaceView.setVerticalScrollBarEnabled(true); and I tried awakenScrollBars(); whenever the user touches the SurfaceView, however none of those displays the scrollbars.

So, is it possible to display the standard Android scrollbar on a SurfaceView?

Comment: Have you tried using a scrollView nesting the SurfaceView? Not sure if it will work, but would be the only way to show 'default' scrollbars.

Comment: Thanks, but in my case the SurfaceView is always the same size as the screen, so it doesn't need to be hosted inside the ScrollView container. Even if I place it there, the scrollbars will always be the same size, which defeats the purpose. And if I make the SurfaceView larger than the screen, so that placing it in a ScrollView would make sense, then I'd run into performance issues, not to mention re-architecting the code. I decided to simply draw custom scrollbars.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

short answer is: no!

everything that the SurfaceView ever draws on the screen is whatever you directly call to be drawn using the whole `lockCanvas` and `unlockCanvasAndPost` that you know about.

Putting those parameters in the XML make it possible for you to read them in Java via the `AttributeSet` in the constructor, but that's only for configuration, it won't drawn anything.